Why doesn't Cobb want to shoot Mal when she is about to kill Fischer?
In Inception, in the scene when Fischer is going to find out his father's last will, we see Mal standing behind him and willing to shoot him. Ariadne tells him that she is not real and that he has to shoot her, but he says, "How do you know that?". Why does Cobb even think that she is real at this point if he knows that he is just a projection? What makes him think that? This is a part of Inception I always find confusing.

The most traumatic experience of Cobb's life was the suicide of his wife - it could be said that the framing narrative of the entire movie is his journey to process and resolve this trauma. The cause of that event is that Mal had lost the capacity to distinguish the dream state from waking life. Thus she thought that killing herself would wake herself from a dream, when in fact it led to her actual death and to lifelong grief for Cobb and their children.
Thus he clearly knows that it is possible for people to lose the ability to distinguish dreaming from reality - if it happened to her, it could happen to him, particularly as they shared the experience of subjective decades in limbo.
Your question states that he knows that Mal is a projection, but in fact the point of the movie is that he is in no way certain of that. From early on in the movie, such as when waiting for Arthur in the hotel room after the failure to extract information from Saito, we see him reality testing, with his pistol out, ready to shoot himself if the test fails:

He is also questioned several times by others as to whether he is able to distinguish reality from dreaming - Ariadne quite quickly challenges him on this point, for example. It is also noted that he breaks his own rules about ways to keep safe from losing the distinction - such as him creating dreams that involve real places and experiences from his past. He explicitly tells Ariadne to never do this, so he must know that he has been putting himself at risk for quite some time.
So Cobb's hesitation to shoot Mal is entirely consistent with his character arc to that point. He then realises his failure and the consequences of it - by not recognising that Mal is only a projection, he has condemned both Fischer and Saito to limbo, and caused the failure of the operation.
Ariadne then comes up with a scheme that will give some hope for the operation to continue. But Cobb is now armed with certainty that he is indeed dreaming and that Mal is a projection. This leads to his ability to finally confront her in limbo, when he has the conversation about her not having all the perfections and imperfections of his actual but now dead wife. This is in effect the culmination of the emotional and narrative arc for his character and the movie itself. The rest (saving Fischer and Saito, Fischer's encounter with his father, and in the real world, crossing the US border) is just tidying up. Although you might of course debate the meaning of the very last shot…

Cobb knows that Mal has died for real. Given this knowledge, how can he have any doubts that the Mal in the scene is a projection? Does he think that her death could possibly happen in a dream and so she would still be alive?

The first sentence of your answer: "The most traumatic experience of Cobb's life was the suicide of his wife". Or are you saying that he got so much traumatized by what he isn't sure is real?

He certainly knows that he could mistake reality for dreaming (as Mal did, assuming he accepts she died for real). Your answer showcases it well. But other way around — mistaking dreaming for reality? Fearing that that deeply nested dream where the final battle takes place could in fact be real, whilst Mal's death could be a dream? I don't buy it.

Cobb and Mal were trapped in Limbo together for subjective decades. This "unformed dream space" that both of them created now comprises elements of both of their psyches. Clearly some part of her personal memories persist within Cobb, to the point that he interacts with her as if she's a real person.
Cobb raises the question; What if her mind now exists within his mind? What if she's not a simple projection of his memories, but actually a real thinking being in her own right, living on inside the recesses of his mind?
To that end he can't shoot her or kill her. Maybe that's not just a fancy 3D picture of his wife, but his actual wife, or at the very least some part of her. That being the case, shooting her in the face isn't palatable to him.

Maybe you've seen zombie movies/shows. It's a very common trope for people to not be able to kill the zombie version of their loved one, even when they are actively aware that zombies have no memories of the person whose body they're using. Even with all that knowledge, and them going to die at the hands of this zombie, they just can't bring themselves to pull the trigger. Their mind cannot allow them to harm the person who (looks like) their loved one.
This is not true for every character in a zombie movie, but it tends to be true for characters who have already particularly struggled with the death of this loved one.
Cobb has definitely struggled with Mal's death. Him being unable to pull the trigger even knowing she's not real is realistic.

There's a second argument to be made here. The movie ends on Cobb being reunited with his kids, but the final scene focuses on the spinning top and leaves it unanswered whether this proves it's a dream or not. Whether it's a dream or not is irrelevant for my current point.
What is relevant, however, is that Cobb walks away from the totem1, indicating that he no longer cares whether it's a dream or reality. He just wants to be with his kids. At some point, Cobb transitioned from very much caring about knowing what's real, to letting go of that need.
With that in mind, let's revisit this scene:

Ariadne tells him that she is not real and that he has to shoot her, but he says, "How do you know that?".

What Cobb might be saying here isn't "I think this is reality and that Mal is actually 100% real", he might be saying:

How do you know that this world is less valid than what we call the "real" world? At least this one has got Mal in it.

Based on the ending, my read on this scene is that it's an early indication that Cobb is letting go of his need to distinguish reality from dream, because he can only be with Mal (and potentially his kids) in a dream, and that's what he wants.

1 I'm ignoring the "Cobb's wedding ring is his totem" argument here because as far as we can tell, he isn't checking his wedding ring either. Whatever the totem, Cobb has clearly ceased to care about it in favor of his kids.
